# Updating an AWS ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs

I have a service running on AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS). My setup is a relatively simple one. It operates with a single task definition and the following details:

- Desired capacity set at 2
- Minimum healthy set at 50%
- Maximum available set at 200%
- Tasks run with 80% CPU and memory reservations

Initially, I am able to get the necessary EC2 instances registered to the cluster that holds the service without a problem. The associated task then starts running on the two instances. As expected – given the CPU and memory reservations – the tasks take up almost the entirety of the EC2 instances' resources.

Sometimes, I want the task to use a new version of the application it is running. In order to make this happen, I create a revision of the task, de-register the previous revision, and then update the service. Note that I have set the minimum healthy percentage to require `2 * 0.50 = 1` instance running at all times and the maximum healthy percentage to permit up to `2 * 2.00 = 4` instances running.

Accordingly, I expected 1 of the de-registered task instances to be drained and taken offline so that 1 instance of the new revision of the task could be brought online. Then the process would repeat itself, bringing the deployment to a successful state.

Unfortunately, the cluster does nothing. In the `events` log, it tells me that it cannot place the new tasks, even though the process I have described above would permit it to do so.

How can I get the cluster to perform the behavior that I am expecting? I have only been able to get it to do so when I manually register another EC2 instance to the cluster and then tear it down after the update is complete (which is not desirable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same issue where the tasks used to get stuck and had no space to place them. Below snippet from AWS doc on [updating a service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html) helped me to make the below decision.

> If your service has a desired number of four tasks and a maximum
>   percent value of 200%, the scheduler may start four new tasks before
>   stopping the four older tasks (provided that the cluster resources
>   required to do this are available). The default value for maximum
>   percent is 200%.

We should have the **cluster resources available / container instances available** to have the new tasks get started so they can start and the older one can drain.

*These are the things i do*

1. Before doing a service update add like 20% capacity to your cluster. You can use the ASG (Autoscaling group) commandline and from the desired capacity add 20% to your cluster. This way you will have some additional instance during deployment.
2. Once you have the instance the new tasks will start spinning up quickly and the older one will start draining.

**But does this mean i will have extra container instances ?**

Yes, during the deployment you will add some instances but as the older tasks drain they will hang around. The way to remove them is

Create a `MemoryReservationLow` alarm (~70% threshold in your case) for like 25 mins (longer duration to be sure that we have over commissioned). As the reservation will go low once you have those extra server not being used they can be removed.

Comment: This is more or less what I've been doing, but the memory alarm is a good idea I didn't even think about. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before. If your port mapping is attempting to map a static host port to the container within the task, you need more cluster instances.

Also this could be because there is not enough available memory to meet the memory (soft or hard) limit requested by the container within the task.

Comment: In your first paragraph, why do you think that is the case? 
As for your second paragraph, as I've said, I'm positive that the instance does not have enough memory to have multiple task revisions on it simultaneously. I'm looking for (at least) one of the instances to be automatically killed and replaced by the new revision altogether.

Comment: Looks like some people have downvoted this answer. However, it highlighted the issue for me. I don't have an ASG set up and my port mappings were preventing the service spinning up new tasks. Thanks!